# What defines Ansible Galaxy role's version?

Tags: package, version, ansible, provisioning, ansible-galaxy

In [documentation of Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/intro) I found you can install specific version of a role. I was not able to find what defines the version in role itself. Is it Git tag, some key in *meta/main.yaml*, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install a version simply git tag it:

```
$ git tag v1.0
$ git push origin v1.0
```

Then from the man page you can install the specific Role version:

```
"ansible-galaxy install [options] [-r FILE | role_name(s)[,version] | tar_file(s)]"
```

Comment: Thank you. Few moments ago I've noticed the "Adding repo tags as role versions" at https://galaxy.ansible.com/imports :)